# EmberJS Application how to handle 419 error

Tags: javascript, http, ember.js, xmlhttprequest

I am wondering if there is a standard way in an ember.js application that for ANY request that returns back a 419 to redirect to a specific route (or in my case force a refresh on the page). I am using ember-graph (similar to ember-data), so I thought maybe this can be handled via the adapter.

I know I can go through each of my server requests throughout the application and check once returned for a 419 and then handle it that way, but the application was written prior to me and I want to see if there is a way to do it for all requests without having to find each request.

Comment: I would suggest to create a abstract/base route that checks for authentication on `beforeModel` and also add an error action that handles 401/419 and redirect people to your "sign in" route and clears any csrf status, if any. Then all routes that require authentication would `extend` this base class